# Animated GIFs in Dynamic Previews Enum

Tags: python

Is there any possibility to load animated gifs as a custom icon, which then would be viewed as animated sequence right in the preview? for now, it's just blank and no static preview generated

For testing I used the "Ui previews dynamic enum" template in python templates (in Text editor)

[image]

EDIT: IF there is no possibility to load gif, anyone here knows the alternative?   Maybe fake somehow animated preview, but for user it'll be looked like gif animation

Comment: AFAIK animated gifs are not supported by blender.

Comment: One option coul be to draw your own stuff with [bgl module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bgl.html) somewhere in the UI. You would have to update that draw call in [app.handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html) to make an animation or to use a [modal operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#modal-execution) if you needed to react to user input.

Answer (score 2):

**Fudge it via the draw system.**

Emulating the frames of an animated gif by using the 4 triangle icons. The simple panel template has been edited to add this "animated" icon to a label.  The icon will step thru its list when the draw is called and panel updated. Mousing over the area, scrolling the area etc will *tick* the animation.

```
import bpy

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"
    i = 0
    icons = ['TRIA_RIGHT',
             'TRIA_DOWN',
             'TRIA_LEFT',
             'TRIA_UP']

    @classmethod
    def icon(cls):
        cls.i += 1
        if cls.i >= len(cls.icons):
            cls.i = 0
        return cls.icons[cls.i]

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label("Anim %d" % self.i, icon=self.icon())

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Ok that's not too impressive, need some way to tie it to time better.  As an example  redraw the properties area on a frame change. Run code and start an animation to see effect.

```
import bpy

def redraw_props(scene):
    for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if a.type == 'PROPERTIES':
            a.tag_redraw()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(redraw_props)
```